# How to find a classes inherited non-monodevelop class from a third class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D RPG and I have the class "BaseEnemy" which applies to all enemies in the game. It contains their stat definitions, base functions all enemies share, etc. Each enemy gets their own individual script which then inherits the BaseEnemy Class and sets it's stats using the BaseEnemy Constructor, like so.

```
public class LesserSlime : MonoBehaviour {

public BaseEnemy myEnemy = new BaseEnemy(1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5);
public EnemyHealthBar myHealthBar;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myEnemy.IsSelected = false;        
}
```

My problem is I'm trying to make a generic battle controller for turn handling, and figuring out which enemy is selected, which when initialized at the start of the battle makes an array of all GameObjects tagged "enemy" at the start:

```
public class BattleController : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] Enemies;
```

My problem is from there I don't know how to access the "BaseEnemy" for each indiviual enemy, since they may have different enemy scripts on them(one may be a slime, one may be a fairy, etc.) but all call their own individual instance of the BaseEnemy class. Is there anyway I can find an access them from the BattleController class, or should I be going about this a different way?

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you make your enemy classes inherit from BaseEnemy, then have BaseEnemy inherit from MonoBehaviour? That way you can use `GetComponent<BaseEnemy>()` regardless of which enemy type it is.

Comment: I...didn't even realize I could do that. Thanks!
EDIT:
Now I'm getting this error "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all"

If I use AddComponent, then I can't call the constructor to set the base stats, no?

Comment: You're right that you won't be able to call the constructor once you make BaseEnemy inherit from MonoBehaviour, but that's fine - you can just set the values you need in the Start() method, or even take a code-free approach: setting the values of the fields in the editor (you may need to mark them as serialized for them to show up).

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1**

You make an interface such as

```
public interface IEnemy {
    BaseEnemy GetBase();
}
```

and then have the enemy classes inherit it

```
public class Slime : MonoBehaviour, IEnemy
```

then you can access it like this from battle controller

```
Enemies[x].GetComponent<IEnemy>().GetBase();
```

**Option #2**

You could make BaseEnemy inherit Monobehaviour

```
pubilc class BaseEnemy : MonoBehaviour
```

and then the enemies inherit just BaseEnemy

```
public class Slime : BaseEnemy
```

and then access it like this

```
 Enemies[x].GetComponent<BaseEnemy>()
```

**Option #3**

You make a BaseUnityEnemy class

```
public class BaseUnityEnemy : MonoBehaviour {
     public BaseEnemy myEnemy;
     public EnemyHealthBar myHealthBar;
}
```

Then have all your enemies inherit that

```
public class LesserSlime : BaseUnityEnemy {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        myEnemy = new BaseEnemy(1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5);
        myEnemy.IsSelected = false;        
    }
}
```

And you can access it like so

```
Enemies[x].GetComponent<BaseUnityEnemy>().myEnemy
```